# Error script wordpress

Tags: wordpress

necesito ayuda me sale error en wordpress y no se a que se deba
(index):1047 GET https://www.deconservicescol.com/wp-content/uploads/pum/pum-site-scripts.js?defer&generated=1539008904&ver=1.7.30 403

mire el depurador y en index aparece esto como error

pero no se que hacer hay, como lo soluciono?

Comment: la configuración del servidor debe estar evitando que se ejecuten scripts desde wp-content/uploads, tendrías que darle permiso a la carpeta de ese plugin

Comment: y como le doy permisos?